# Mobile and Desktop media query priority

Tags: html, css, media-queries, web-frontend

I'm a beginner in front-end web development. I want to know the order of priority when writing CSS media queries in desktop first approach. Do i write mobile queries first and tablet queries below it, in this manner:

`/*Desktop CSS*/`
`/*Media query for tablet*/`
`/*Media query for Mobile*/`

or the other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write anywhere but if you are a beginner then I suggest you create a separate file for responsive CSS so that you will not confused.
SO in the style.css desktop approach and in responsive.css all media queries for mobile and tablet.
Standered Media queries:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1200px){} /* Desktop */
@media screen and (min-width: 1025px) and (max-width: 1199px){} /* small laptop */
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px){} /* tablet */
@media screen and (min-width: 575px) and (max-width: 767.98px){} /* tablet and large mobiles */
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px){} /* Mobile*/
```

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the breakpoints too. I've been seeing a lot different stuff for different screen sizes online. I'll use the separate file approach for now.